# Best/Easiest way to grab data from one app/website, process it and do something in another app/website?

Tags: android, web

I want to either on a Windows server or on my Android phone process info from one service (Google Messages) and if it meets certain criteria, do something with another service (Google Voice).

I am a developer, but this is outside of my range of expertise.  Specifically, when I receive a text message from certain numbers, I want to send a Google Voice message using the contents of the text message.

GV/Messages both have an Android app and have web versions.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is a bit confused.  If you want to do something whenever you get a text from a certain number, you don't need to do anything with Google Messages.  Android has built in SMS functionality in the OS, Messages is just a UI over that.  You can read the incoming messages, and react accordingly.  Google "how to read text messages programmatically Android" you'll see thousands of examples.

Now doing something with Google Voice as a result-  I'd check to see if GV has an API.  From what I can see, there's no official one but lots of ones people have reversed engineered.  Those may work, they may not.  If you want to try one, carefully read all of the source yourself to assure that there's no malware.  Your other option is to reverse engineer it yourself, which isn't going to be easy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The goal is  to be able to text from my watch.  GV does not have a Wear OS app.  This is an attempt to hack that.  Sending a text via messages to someone is useless because no one has my real phone number.  I was hoping I could use an app like Tasker, but it doesn't appear to have that functionality.